# is there a Keras equivalent to np.nanmean()?

Tags: python, keras, backend

In Keras loss function I would like to have a `np.nanmean()` equivalent:

In the loss function en equivalent of the following simplified example failed for obvious reasons. Could not find a way to handle that, for example using `K.gather()`.

A simplified example:

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np


nominator = np.array([-6,4,-8,7,0,5,1,-2])
denominator = np.array([1,4,5,7,9,0,12,0])

Nom = K.variable(nominator,dtype='int32')
DeNom = K.variable(denominator,dtype='int32')

Ratio = Nom/DeNom
Loss = K.sum(Ratio)
```

Due to the 0s in the denominator, this will return a nan in the Loss function:

```
K.eval(Loss)
nan
```

I would like to have some way to either produce an equivalent to

```
Loss = K.nansum(Ratio)
```

Or an equivalent to indices:

```
Filter_Ratio = K.gather(Ratio,K.any(DeNom))
Loss = K.sum(Filter_Ratio)
```

Here the `Filter_Ratio = [-6,4,-8,7,0,1]/[1,4,5,7,9,12]`

But there is no `K.nansum()` and `K.gather()` does not work like this.

The numpy implementation I wanted to transfer to Keras is:

```
nominator = np.array([-6,4,-8,7,0,5,1,2])
denominator = np.array([1,4,5,7,9,0,12,0])
ind = denominator!=0
ratio = nominator[ind]/denominator[ind]

loss = np.sum(ratio)
```

Comment: Could you specify desired behaviour? In case you've described, `Loss = np.nansum(Ratio)` will output nan because of +/-inf present at the same time

Comment: I want to remove all the elements where there is 0 in the denominator for the operation. I have added an explanation and numpy implementation.

Perhaps it is not precise to use np.nansum() as well. Becasue that also would not work. The problem remain the same. I need to devide vector by vector, ignoring elements with zero in the denominator. 

The good approach is to include an indices that remove those elements. So I have added a numpy implementation explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf


Nom = tf.constant([-6,4,-8,7,0,5,1,-2], dtype='int32')
DeNom = tf.constant([1,4,5,7,9,0,12,0], dtype='int32')
Ratio = Nom/DeNom
Ratio1 = tf.where(tf.is_inf(Ratio), tf.zeros_like(Ratio), Ratio)
Loss = K.sum(Ratio1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(Loss))
```

Output:

`-5.516666666666667`

- Divide the tensors and replace the infnity values in the `Ratio` tensor with zeros

  `Ratio1 = tf.where(tf.is_inf(Ratio), tf.zeros_like(Ratio), Ratio)`

`tf.where` is very similar to `np.where`

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where